# Raspberry Pi Lifi Proof of Concept Help

Tags: communication

I'm currently an Electronic Engineering student. I'm coming to my third year and I can build a project of my choosing to write my dissertation about. I have decided to do it on Lifi. I would really appreciate some input on this and some experience to help me.

This is only a proof of concept but my plan is to have two lasers on two separate adjustable jigs which have photodiode receivers next to them. When pointed at each other the lasers will line up with the photodiodes.

I want to make the connection full duplex by using a pair of Raspberry Pis or Arduino's. As a proof of concept, I wish to just do some file sharing between two computers using this setup and the microcontrollers as middlemen. I was going to use a digital regenerator on each end to convert it back to serial and remove noise.

Is this achievable or am I setting the bar too high here? bare in mind that I can program in C and would have to learn python to code the raspberries.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Not a good place for this question, the electronics stack exchange would be better but still not a place for a discussion about a project. Do Some research, you will find experiments that have been done before. IR light can be used for lifi as well

Comment: Thanks, I would rather use lasers as I want to prove you can use this long range even in the daylight. Oh okay, that makes sense! Ill use electronics next time.

Comment: Note: Raspberry Pi is itself just Linux computer so you wouldn't need middlemen. Conceptually, you would need "regenerators with a USB plug".  Python is not required and you can stick with C.

Comment: @AdamHughes, `IR light` and `laser` are not mutually exclusive .... there is such a thing as an IR laser .... usually of CO2 type .... used for cutting stuff ....